# Control of user session with ASPXAUTH cookie and asp.net_sessionID cookies

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

If I have an ASPXAUTH cookie set as a session cookie, timeout 10 minutes, but no asp.net_sessionID cookie, will the user timeout in
a) ten minutes from login
b) ten minutes from their last request to the server

Will this behaviour change if I also send an asp.net_sessionID cookie?

This is for a JSON service built on a Sitecore backend providing content for a native iPad app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The aspxauth cookie timeout is from the time the last request was received.

**Timeout**

> Specifies the time, in integer minutes, after which the cookie
>   expires. If the SlidingExpiration attribute is true, the timeout
>   attribute is a sliding value, expiring at the specified number of
>   minutes after the time that the last request was received.

See the msdn [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/1d3t3c61%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for details

The ASP.NET_SessionId cookie is used to track session state, its unrelated to the ASPXAUTH cookie which is purley for authentication purposes.